# Is there a file explorer tool for Git

Tags: windows, git

I have been looking for a tool that will allow me to select a branch/commit in Git and have it display a tree view for the files in that branch/commit. Specifically, I am looking for a Windows tool that will work similar to how Windows Explorer works to display files with the branch/commit as the root of the tree and expanding/selecting a branch/commit would show you the files committed in that branch/commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitExtensions is doing it quite well.

1. Open your repository
2. Select your commit
3. Select the tab 'File tree'

Comment: This is almost exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

git-gui? There are other clients out there (tortoise integration with windows explorer)

Comment: I just took another look at git-gui, but I cannot see a way to open a file tree view for a branch/commit.  Am I missing something? Tortoise doesn't do this either. It integrates with Windows Explorer but it doesn't allow you to select a branch/commit to see what the file tree looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot to pick, you can read about the and try some of them:

```
#1 SmartGit
#2 GitKraken
#3 GitExtensions
#4 SourceTree
#5 TortoiseGit
#6 GitHub Desktop
#7 Git for Windows
#8 Magit
#9 Aurees
#14 Git BASH
```

Comment: I have tried GitKraken and SourceTree, but I have not been able to find a way to view the file tree.  Can you explain how to get to the file tree view?